# Polymorphic Assocations using Integer ID type fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a table `Foo` that has a polymorphic belongs_to association called `bar`. The `foos` table has the standard `bar_id` column. However, instead of a string-based `bar_type` column, I have an integer `bar_type_id` column. This column references the `id` column in the table `bar_types`. `bar_types.name` holds the name of the class that represents the class of the particular `bar` instance.

Does Rails (ideally >=2.3.10) allow for this type of polymorphic association?

Comment: As far as it is not standart polymorphic association you should write it by yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We did it by overriding the `association_class` method in a new module and included it using the `:extend` option. Also created a integer to string mapping hash to make things easier.

In `config/initializers` directory or anywhere you like, create a file and define the hash
`INT_OBJECT_TYPE_TO_CLASSNAME = { 0 => "Project", 1 => "Task", 2 => "Timesheet" }`

```
class CommentObjectType < ActiveRecord::Base
  module ClassNamesAsInt
    def association_class
      return INT_OBJECT_TYPE_TO_CLASSNAME[restricted_object_type].constantize
    end
  end
end
```

In comments.rb

```
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true, :extend => CommentObjectType::ClassNamesAsInt
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm making use of the [polymorphic integer type](https://github.com/doliveirakn/polymorphic_integer_type) gem, written by one of my co-workers. It's slightly easier to use than the examples given above, in my opinion. For example, after configuring the mapping, you change from:

```
belongs_to :actor,              polymorphic: true
```

to the new format:

```
belongs_to :actor,              polymorphic: true, integer_type: true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for this.

First is easy:

```
has_many :bars, :conditions => "whatever you want"
```

Second could be tricky:

```
set_inheritance_column :bar_type_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can play around

```
belongs_to :bar, :class_name => proc{ BarType.find(self.bar_type_id).name }, :foreign_key => :bar_id
```