# doubts in polymorphic in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models photo, post and comments. In photo there is a polymorphic association attachable_id and attachable_type column. I want to assign attachable_type value 1,2 for post and comments respectively.

I have added following code

Photo.rb

```
 belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
```

Post.rb

```
has_many  :photos, -> { where(attachable_type: 1) }, as: :attachable, class_name: "Photo", dependent: :destroy
```

Comment.rb

```
 has_many  :photos, -> { where(attachable_type: 2) }, as: :attachable, class_name: "Photo", dependent: :destroy
```

But when I try to get the count of photos of a post using

```
self.photos.count
```

The query generated is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`attachable_id` = 853 AND `photos`.`attachable_type` = 0 AND `photos`.`attachable_type` = 1
```

I don't know how `photos`.`attachable_type` = 0 added to the query. Please help me to avoid this from the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attachable_type` should be `string`, not `integer`.

If you define when `attachable_type` is 1, it belongs to `post`, then there's no need to use `polymorphic`, you have just custom it.

The usage for the `polymorphic` is wrong, `attachable_type` should be `the model's class name`.

for example

```
2.3.1 :001 > Notification.last
=> #<Notification id: 3733, notify_attachable_id: 489, 
notify_attachable_type: "Demander", created_at: "2017-04-10 
08:36:46", updated_at: "2017-04-10 08:36:46", already_read: false>
```

Chang it to this

**Post.rb**

```
has_many :photos, as: :attachable
```

**Comment.rb**

```
has_many :photos, as: :attachable
```

and create the photos in this way

```
post.photos.create(image_url: 'http://xx.jpg')
```

it will auto fill `attachable_type` and `attachable_id` fields.

If you really want the type to be `integer` field, please check this refer, [Polymorphic Assocations using Integer ID type fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131311/polymorphic-assocations-using-integer-id-type-fields). And my opinion is that then you just have no need to use `polymorphic`, just write some custom methods, it's simple.

Comment: can we use attachable_type as tiny int instead of string. I want to optimize the size of the column

Comment: check this https://github.com/doliveirakn/polymorphic_integer_type, but i haven't use it before. if you want it to be tiny int, then you need write custom code. because it doesn't support officially