# has_many polymorphic relationship where our _type field is an int?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

We have an app in Rails 4 (but soon to be Rails 5) that has a polymorphic log class that we inherited from a Django app.

In a traditional polymorphic relation, the objects would have source_type and source_id, which would be things like `'some_class'` and `123`.

In our little model, we have `content_type` and `content_id` which unfortunately map to two ints, where the int in `content_type` further points to a `ContentType` model that -- to further complicate things -- dont map to Rails-ey types (`'some_type'` but rather django-ey `'some type class'`.

It's a mess.

Is there any way to override the value used in looking in a polymorphic association (e.g. instead of using `'some_class'`, use `11`) -- but just for the association? There is an answer for a [problem somewhat similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131311/polymorphic-assocations-using-integer-id-type-fields) to ours, but it is 4 years old and it overrides association_class. We still use some of this strange Django voodoo elsewhere in our codebase, so overrides feel like they'd cause more problems than solve.

Comment: It's not clear at all what the relationship is between the Django app and your app, and whether it even matters. Is there a reason this has a [django] tag? Is your Django app still relevant? Are you replacing or co-existing? In other words, can you refactor the Rails model to be more "Rails-ey"?

Comment: Also, it would help if you provide more actual context (i.e. code). What are your pertinent models or table structures?